# Can Indexers of a property work in xaml binding in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, binding

something i do wrong? anyone gives some suggestions

according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx)

Indexers of a property can be specified within square brackets following the property name where the indexer is applied. For instance, the clause Path=ShoppingCart[0] sets the binding to the index that corresponds to how your property's internal indexing handles the literal string "0". Multiple indexers are also supported.

i put Indexers of a property in my xaml

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePathList[0]}" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
```

i do not give the viewmodel code because i am pretty sure ListImagePathList have data.

**EDIT***
more detail: ImagePathList[0] is a web image url

***EDIT FOR Brendan***

model is Article

```
public class Article : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private long _Id;
        public long ID
        {
            get { return _Id; }
            set
            {
                if (_Id != value)
                {
                    _Id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        private string _subject;
        public string Subject
        {
            get
            {
                return _subject;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_subject != value)
                {
                    _subject = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private string _words;
        public string Words
        {
            get
            {
                return _words;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_words != value)
                {
                    _words = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private DateTime _publishDate;
        public DateTime PublishDate
        {
            get
            { return _publishDate; }
            set
            {
                if (_publishDate != value)
                {
                    _publishDate = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public List<string> ImagePathList = new List<string>();

        private string _firstImage;
        public string FirstImage
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstImage;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_firstImage != value)
                {
                    _firstImage = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

ArticleViewModel is in below; **All data returned from network is correct!**

```
public class ArticleListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {    
        public ArticleListViewModel()
        {
            this.ArticleCollection = new ObservableCollection<Article>();                
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Article> ArticleCollection
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public void LoadPage(int pageNumber)
        {
            if (pageNumber == 1)
            {
                this.ArticleCollection.Clear();
            }

            IsLoading = true;
            ReadArticleList(pageNumber);

        }

        private async void ReadArticleList(int pageNumber)
        {
            try
            {

                List<Article> articleList = new List<Article>();
                articleList = await CollectionHttpClient.GetArticlesByPageAsync(pageNumber);

                this.ArticleCollection.Add(item);

                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.HResult == -2146233088 && ex.Message.Equals("Response status code does not indicate success: 404 ()."))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The network is not set right. Internet cannot be accessed.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("sorry, no data.");
                }

            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is your image a resource, contetn or it is downloaded to IsolatedStorage?

Comment: @Romasz download, see my EDIT in question

Comment: Have you tried to bind it to property with getter returning an absolute Uri dependant on your ImagePathList[0]?

Comment: @Romasz could u give more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML code you show is fine.

There may be a problem with the `DataContext`. Maybe the page `DataContext` has not been set? Or maybe the the `DataContext` has changed e.g. inside an `ItemTemplate`

Otherise the problem is probably to do with the bound property. Try the following

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _imagePathList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> ImagePathList {
    get { return this._imagePathList; }
    set {
        if (this._imagePathList != value)
        {
            this._imagePathList = value;
            // I'm going to assume you have the NotifyPropertyChanged
            // method defined on the view-model
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

`ObservableCollection` is in `System.Collections.ObjectModel` and is  like `List` but if elements are added/removed then the `PropertyChanged` event is fired. Also note that any bound property must have a `get` associated with it for it to work at all.

Another possibility is that `ImagePathList` was not assigned to or is empty - in which case, make sure you assign to it!

In case you have not yet implemented the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method, here it is ...

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You will also need to add `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to the containing class e.g.

```
public class MyViewModelClass : INoftifyPropertyChanged 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: please see ***EDIT FOR Brendan*** in question

Comment: So there are a couple of problems, first of all all bound properties must have a getter, second, instead of a `List<string>` you should use an `ObservableCollection<string>`. Replace the definition for `ImagePathList` for the definition I provide above, it should work ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem concerns the place where your images come from. As it is said at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.105).aspx):

> You can set the Source by specifying an absolute URL (e.g. http://contoso.com/myPicture.jpg) or specify a URL relative to the XAP file of your application.
>
> You can set this property in XAML, but in this case you are setting the property as a URI. The XAML behavior relies on underlying type conversion that processes the string as a URI, and calls the BitmapImage(Uri) constructor. This in turn potentially requests a stream from that URI and returns the image source object.

Just for test - place some images in your project and then set ImagePathList to them. See if that works (it should as I think). Or see if you can get BitmapImage(ImagePathList);

It's hard for me to say now (as I don't know how your ImagePathList looks like) what could be a reason of the failure. But if I were you, I would test this.

---

I would advise to use a property (or you can use converter which will also do the job):

```
// a property in your class
public Uri FirstImage
{
   get
   {
        return new Uri(ImagePathList.FirstOrDefault(), UriKind.Absolute);
   }
}
```

On the other hand if you are downloading images to IsolatedStorage then you will have to use another property, that will load BitmapImage from IS:

```
public BitmapImage FirstImage // getter - BitmapImage
{
    get
    {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImagePath[0])) return null;
       BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage();

       using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
       using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = ISF.OpenFile(ImagePath[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            temp.SetSource(file);
       return temp;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: let me clear my question here. add another property did work for me. and i m sure it can work. My code work well for now since i have other solution for this. but i just want dig more. My question here is that MSDN said "Indexers of a property can be specified within square brackets...."  why in WP8. i used ImagePathList[0] and it does not work.

Comment: @max I've rebuild my answer after some research.

Comment: Thnx for your answer, Romasz,  @Brendan's answer works for me. it is the no getter method for ImagePathList